# Repeating task in android will takes more battery power if we use alarm manager?

Tags: android

We are using following code for repeating task:

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
int interval=15000;
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

Will this drains battery?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read:

[Scheduling Repeating Alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Here you'll find all your answers!

Answer (score 0):

The sort answer "no". The waiting alarm feature doesn't consume the battery.

But, obviously, if the interval is about several seconds the device will consume battary (if you try to call very often). In other cases this is the best way to do the work. If you want to recall the service namely 15 seconds and calculations are huge the devices will never sleep. In this case this will consume.